# How to test node.js cli modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a node cli module for file encryption. I have completed the functionality but I haven't tested it.

The cli command to execute module is

- `encrypt -t e a.txt a.out`
- Usage: index [options] source-file dest-file

  Options:

  -h, --help         output usage information

  -t, --type   type of operation, encrypt or decrypt

**Then it will ask for password for e.g**

encrypt -t e a.txt a.out

Enter password: ****

> Now the problem is how do I test this cli module, I went through node.js [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) documentation but I was unable accept the password. Please help me the get the solution.

Here is my module dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
  "co": "^4.6.0",
  "co-prompt": "^1.0.0",
  "commander": "^2.9.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "chai": "^3.5.0",
  "child-process-promise": "^1.1.0",
  "execa": "^0.2.2",
  "mocha": "^2.4.5"
}
```

Comment: You can use an npm module like "keypress" to get input from cli. Try this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/keypress

Comment: Both [exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) and [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) methods return a [`ChildProcess` object](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess). You should be able to use its [`.stdin`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin) property to send any data to the spawned process, just as if you've entered it from your keyboard.

Comment: It will help if we will see some working example of an `encrypt` module you're trying to test. It could be either a [minimal artificial example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or just a link to your project.